# How to check if a machine is able to connect through mstsc using C#

Tags: c#

Check through C# code if a machine is able to connect through remote desktop connection MSTSC. I need a logic which takes machine name as input and returns result in bool.

For example:

If I connect a machine/server using remote desktop connection in windows manually. Few machines are able to connect and few are throwing that default prompt "The remote desktop can't connect remote computer due to following reasons: 1... 2... 3..."
Hence, I want a C# logic which gives me true or false if machine can be accessible through RDP or not.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: it won't be synchronous. you could look to see if port 3389 is open, but that won't guarantee thats RDC.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.terminalserversession(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

> Gets a value indicating whether the calling process is associated with
>   a Terminal Services client session.

You can find an example here: [Remote Desktop using C#.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET)

Comment: Hey, This example suggests to use a different dll but I can't use any 3rd party DLL or any AcitveX component in my application due to project limitations.